# Ternary operator on increment integer

Tags: c#, ternary-operator

Can someone please tell me why the code below is not working?

```
    int prePos = 0;
    int preNeg = 0;

    int postPos = 0;
    int postNeg = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < pin1.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        preNeg++ ? pin1[i, 0] < 0 : prePos++; //not working
        pin2[i, 0] < 0 ? postNeg++ : postPos++; //not working
    }
```

So the condition is if `pin1[i, 0]` is smaller than zero, `preNeg` get incremented by one. Else `prePos` should be inceremeted. I can do this by normal if else but why this ternary is not working?

Comment: The result of the ternary operator is an expression. It's the same as writing `3;` as a line of code. This won't work.

Comment: If you can do it by normal which probably is more readable considering you do need an else condition why don't you keep it like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    preNeg++ ? pin1[i, 0] < 0 : prePos++; //not working
    pin2[i, 0] < 0 ? postNeg++ : postPos++; //not working
```

Because ternary operator returns a value that is assigned to a variable or property;

like

```
int a = true ? 1 : 0;
```

a will have 1

syntax of ternary operator is

```
var variable = condition ? 
              value_to_return_in_variable_if_condition_true :  
              value_to_return_in_variable_if_condition_false;
```

Moreover ternary operator is used to assign value to a single variable. not to two variables.

Answer (score 4):

The ternary operator is an *operator* which evaluates to an expression (something that indicates a value) and can therefore not be used as a statement anymore than an expression  using `+` can be used as a statement (`1+1;` is illegal as a statement).

What makes this particular use of the ternary operator somewhat different is the use of the increment (`++`) operator.  Using the `++` operator performs an operation on the variable (increments it by one) as well as outputs a value (the value of the variable before it was incremented when `++` placed after the variable).

As such, the following would achieve what you are trying to do but then you would be left with an unused variable (not to mention unclear code) so I cannot see this being used in practice.

```
var currentValue = pin1[i, 0] < 0 ? postNeg++ : postPos++;
```

As has already been mentioned, your best bet is to go with a normal `if`/`else`.  That is what it is there for.

Comment: Another way to do it: "preNeg += pin[i, 0] < 0 ? 1 : (++prePos == prePos ? 0 : 0);". Someone should kill you for using that, though.